# How to configure Multiple Sites using Ubuntu + Apache with the same IP on different physical servers?

Tags: apache2

I have two Moodle sites. An old one and a new one. Each of them on Ubuntu Server with Apache on different physical servers. Is it possible to make them work using the same external ip and domain name with different ports? How should I configure apache and its virtual host?

Example> [www.example.com/moodle1](http://www.example.com/moodle1) << 111.111.11.11:80 and [www.example.com/moodle2](http://www.example.com/moodle2) << 11.111.11.11:8081

what is the most viable solution?

thanks

Comment: You do not need to use different ports. Apache can support millions of websites using the same installation. Set up some virtual hosts using the correct domain details and you'll be good to go.

Comment: Thank you Matigo. I found configurations of virtual hosts on the internet for multiple sites on just one ubuntu + apache server. However I have two ubuntu servers and each one on a different physical server and only one domain address for both, this is not working. Do you know of a website or article that explains this configuration for different physical servers?

Comment: You had said that you had two installations of Moodle, one new and one old. Are both of these using the very same domain, such as example.com? Or is one of them example.com and the other is learning.example.com? If there is a sub domain, things are simpler. Otherwise you'll be using proxies and doubling bandwidth on one machine …

Comment: Thanks for the answer.It helped a lot.
I have only one Moodle operating (the old one) at www.example.com/moodle and I need to run the second Moodle (the new one) for www.example.com/moodle. It would be much easier to acquire a new IP or subdomain however as government work involves bureaucracy for months and unfortunately due to COVID 19 we need the new Moodle urgently. So I thought that there could be a way to use the same IP and Domain that we have from Old Moodle. If you put the Old Moodle on the same Ubuntu Server as the New Moodle, would it work?

Comment: Yes, you can have multiple Moodle installations on the same server, so long as they are in different directories and use different databases. This would allow you to do a "migration" from the old system to the new when the system is ready.